# How can I partition a table with 100 million rows into 365 subtables (partition by date)?

Tags: postgresql, ddl, database-partitioning

I have a table with about 100 million rows in PostgreSQL. Each row contains a date column. I want to partition the table into 365 child tables (partition by day).

My idea is

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (

    mydatetime TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE,

    other columns .....

)

PARTITION BY LIST COLUMNS(DATE(mydatetime))

(

    PARTITION date20220101 VALUES in ('2022-01-01'),

    PARTITION date20220102 VALUES in ('2022-01-02'),

    ....

)
```

I think this solution is very long. I need a shorter solution. Can you help me?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  100 million records is not that large for a well tuned table and database.

Comment: Also, this syntax has nothing to do with PostgreSQL.

Comment: Apart from the fact that this syntax is invalid for Postgres, if you want 365 partitions you will need to write a SQL that contains the definition of 365 partitions in Postgres. Which means writing or generating 365 `create table` statements.